# Page Overlapped in php using jquery mobile

Tags: php, jquery

I am developing a mobile website using jquery mobile. I had a page name `www.example.com/index.php` that includes `header.php` page. There is the second page like `www.example.com/secondpage.php` that also includes `header.php` page and it contains a link to go the `index.php` page that is `wwww.example.com/index.php`.

The page looks nice when firstly browsed, that is `www.example.com/index.php` layout is well when browsed at first time. When you go to the second page i.e `www.example.com/secondpage.php` and click a link on `secondpage.php` to return back to the first page then it backs to the www.example.com/index.php but there is layout overlapped problem that means same `header.php` is included twice. Other layout is ok.

How do I get the page correct on return visit?

Comment: are you using an iframe or ajax loading into the page?  Or have you included the header in the div with the `data-role="content"` attribute?  A bit of code would be useful here, [please read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you using JavaScript at all on the page? Can you include the code?

Comment: I am not using data-role="content". And header contains an image that links to the htttp://www.example.com/index.php page. No any ajax to load the page. There is simple link tag in image that redirects the secondpage.php to the http://www.example.com/index.php

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note if you are linking from a mobile page that was loaded via Ajax to a page with multiple internal pages, you need to add a rel="external" or data-ajax="false" to the link.For example : .........Please visit the below website for further information.. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a3/docs/pages/docs-pages.html